# How can I parameterize multiple users login in your specflow gherkin (Selenium Webdriver)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I need help please, I have a working Selenium Webdriver/Gherkin/Specflow project that I created. I am trying to migrate my code to another environment (stage), but I only want to make changes in the app.config to switch between the different environments. I have successfully executed the URL switch with app.config using the 'Switch Cases', the problem I am facing now is how to create second login and how will gherkin knows to switch to the specific environment that I am running. Currently I have my username and password store in gherkin like this:

```
Examples:
| firstname | username | password |
| Cam      | Newton     | 12345dev     |
```

This is how I am performing my url switch:

```
switch (environment)
        {
            case "DEV":

                if (!(_driver.Url.Equals(Constants.DEV_LandingPage)))
                {
                    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Constants.DEV_LandingPage);
                }
                break;
            case "STAGE":
                if (!(_driver.Url.Equals(Constants.STAGE_LandingPage)))
                {
                    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Constants.STAGE_LandingPage);
                }
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the scenarios, that you do not specify the user credentials in them. 
So from this Gherkin:

```
Given I log in with username 'Newton' and password '12345dev'
```

to this:

```
Given I log in with valid credentials
```

One of my colleagues wrote an article about it: http://specflow.org/2017/fit-for-purpose-gherkin/

Additional you could specify the valid credentials also in the app.config.

For having different configurations for the stages you could have a look at Targets feature of the SpecFlow+Runner (http://www.specflow.org/plus). Here is an example how it is used to test against different browsers: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest
 This is done via app.config value transformation.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+.

Comment: thanks for your response but that did not answer my question. I am not looking into hardcoding the login credentials